# Xerox 3100MFP Driver for MacOS X 10.6.0 and upper?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, printer

I've an Xerox 3100MFP and can't install it on my iMac because I've updated it.

I've already read the [Xerox Products' Compatibility with Mac - Mac OS X 10.6](http://download.support.xerox.com/pub/drivers/Compatibility_Matrix/other/macosx/en/MacOSX10-6_Matrix.pdf), but it says that it is unsupported!

Can any experts hack a PPD file or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i've discovered how to put macos 10.4 drivers working on macos 10.6, i've installed first the 10.4 drivers ant then I opened the Terminal Console and typed:

```
sudo su -
chown -R root:admin /Library/Printers/Xerox/
chmod 775 /Library/Printers/Xerox/filter/rastertoprinter
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question answered. It just got bumped to the front page by Community.